# Нумерация страниц mpdf

Tags: mpdf

Застрял с нумерацией страниц в `mpdf`.

Вот код:

```
for ($i=0; $i<400; $i++){
  $text = "HELLO PEOPLE #:".$i."<br/>";
  $ht=$ht.$text;
}
$HTML="<html>
<head>
    <link href='../css/style_pdf1.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>
    <body>
        <p> <h1> Џривет! HO HO HO </h1></p>".$ht."
    </body>
</html>";
include("../tools/mpdf/mpdf.php");
$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8','A4', 8, '', 10, 10, 7, 7, 10, 10); //задаем формат, отступы и.т.д.
$mpdf->charset_in = 'windows-1251'; //не забываем про русский
$mpdf->setFooter("Page {PAGENO} of {nb}");
ob_start();
echo $HTML;
$xhtml=ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($xhtml,0); //формируем pdf
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
```

Выдает ошибку:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'ID' in D:\Sites\Portal\tools\mpdf\classes\cssmgr.php on line 1138
>   
>   Warning: Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset in D:\Sites\Portal\tools\mpdf\classes\cssmgr.php on line 1138
>   
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'LANG' in D:\Sites\Portal\tools\mpdf\classes\cssmgr.php on line 1142
>   
>   Warning: Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset in D:\Sites\Portal\tools\mpdf\classes\cssmgr.php on line 1142
>   
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'ID' in D:\Sites\Portal\tools\mpdf\classes\cssmgr.php on line 1193
>   
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'LANG' in D:\Sites\Portal\tools\mpdf\classes\cssmgr.php on line 1193

Подскажите, как побороть?

Comment: Учитесь пользоваться поисковыми системами - https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/issues/37 А вообще mpdf достаточно старая библиотека, часто приходится ручками там подправлять.

Comment: Спасибо. Можете посоветовать хорошую библиотеку создания PDF из php. Знаю есть FPDF, но она планая, что есть из безплатного?

Answer (score 1):

Вдруг поможет. У себя мы используем нумерацию в Header. Вот такой код

```
$mpdf->SetHeader(date("d.m.Y") . '|{PAGENO}/{nb}|' . $pdf_header . '');
```